# Python,vk_api, account.getBanned(сделать массив из id)

Tags: python

Очень простой и глупый вопрос, но тем не менее, я получаю список аккаунтов добавленных в ЧС и вывожу его.

```
a = vk.method('account.getBanned',{'count':200})
print(a['items'])
```

Вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне из полученного сделать массив id пользователей?

Answer (score 0):

```
ids = [item['id'] for item in a['items']]
```